# while saving the snap taken by webcam error shown "incorrect padding"

Tags: python, django

when i delete the image and try to save the profile it shows me an error "incorect padding"

my code is

**Models.py**

```
import webcam.admin
from webcam import widgets
from webcam.fields import CameraField
picture=CameraField('Webcam_Image', format='jpeg', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='pictures')
```

**admin.py**

```
from webcam import widgets
from webcam.fields import CameraField
FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS[CameraField] = {'widget': widgets.CameraWidget}
```

**error**

```
Incorrect padding
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/account/account/8/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: Error
Exception Value:    
Incorrect padding
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py in decodestring, line 321
Python Executable:  /home/cpverma/work/school/env/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/cpverma/work/cpverma/crushernew',
 '/home/cpverma/work/school/env/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/cpverma/work/school/env/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/cpverma/work/school/env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/cpverma/work/school/env/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/cpverma/work/school/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 28 Oct 2015 22:06:04 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to work with the demo provided by the library first and check whats different [here.](https://github.com/saxix/django-webcam/tree/develop/demo)

Comment: when i click on clear button and try to save it again showing me  same error

Comment: @CpVerma post the stack trace in your question so I know what went wrong

Comment: sorry what is stack trace..should i show you the code or error

Comment: @ Hamad AlGhanim,I have updated my question.Please have a look.Thanks